# ofstream : line break in csv file

Tags: c++

I want to write and add a line in my "example.csv" file for each loop.

I'm aware that at the moment my code just replaces each line every time.

The problem is, I don't know how to add a line every time.

Thanks

```
#include <fstream>


void loop() 
{

    getAngles();
    std::cout<<"AngleX="<<angleX-angleX0<<" AngleY="<<angleY-angleY0<<std::endl;

    csvFile.open ("example.csv");
    csvFile << angleX-angleX0 << ";" << angleY-angleY0 <<"\n";
    csvFile.close();

    delay(1000);

}

int main()
{
    setup();

    for (;;) { 
        loop();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you open and close the file each time round the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your file like this:

```
csvFile.open("example.csv", std::ios_base::app);
```

which will append lines to the file instead of overwriting it.